# Intermittent performance issues with Apache ignite 2.7.5

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are facing intermittent performance issues with ignite where response times become very high and we see below error in our logs. We have 10 indexed columns and I don't see any issues with indexes as all the columns in the "where" clause are indexed. Joins are happening on the fields with affinity colocation which means that joins are happening only on the data in a particular node and not across nodes.

```
[21:48:30,765][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%PincodeGrid] Possible too long JVM pause: 4939 milliseconds.
[21:48:30,783][WARNING][query-#120%PincodeGrid%][IgniteH2Indexing] Query execution is too long [time=5052 ms, sql='SELECT
```

Please let me know if you can provide any help on this.

- Apache Ignite version : 2.7.5
- Ignite persistence is enabled (true)
- 2 node cluster in partitioned mode
- RAM - 150 GB per node
- JVM xms and xmx 20G
- Number of records - 160 million
- JVM options -

  /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -XX:+AggressiveOpts -server -Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/etappdata/ignite/logs/PROD/etail-prod-ignite76-163/logs -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M -Xloggc:/etappdata/ignite/logs/PROD/etail-prod-ignite76-163/gc.log -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UseTLAB -verbose:gc -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=false -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8996 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8996 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=etail-prod-ignite76-163 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4g -javaagent:/tmp/apminsight-javaagent-prod/apminsight-javaagent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseG1GC -DIGNITE_QUIET=false -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=/ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin/work/ignite_success_7d9ec20d-9728-475a-aa80-4355eb8eaf02 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=49112 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -DIGNITE_HOME=/ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=./bin/ignite.sh -cp /ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin/libs/*:/ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin/libs/ignite-spring/*:/ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin/libs/licenses/* org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup config/config-cache.xml

  Added additional details

  [04:03:48,251][INFO][main][IgniteKernal%PincodeGrid] IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=PincodeGrid, pubPoolSize=30, svcPoolSize=30, callbackPoolSize=30, stripedPoolSize=30, sysPoolSize=30, mgmtPoolSize=4, igfsPoolSize=30, dataStreamerPoolSize=30, utilityCachePoolSize=30, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=30, igniteHome=/ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin, igniteWorkDir=/ignite/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin/work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@13221655, nodeId=6aee7bb4-2804-4396-a9ec-65abdc9483e3, marsh=BinaryMarshaller [], marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=true, netTimeout=5000, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=0, ackTimeout=0, marsh=null, reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=null, connPlc=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$FirstConnectionPolicy@34123d65, enableForcibleNodeKill=false, enableTroubleshootingLog=false, locAddr=null, locHost=null, locPort=47100, locPortRange=100, shmemPort=-1, directBuf=true, directSndBuf=false, idleConnTimeout=600000, connTimeout=5000, maxConnTimeout=600000, reconCnt=10, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=65536, msgQueueLimit=2048, slowClientQueueLimit=0, nioSrvr=null, shmemSrv=null, usePairedConnections=true, connectionsPerNode=10, tcpNoDelay=true, filterReachableAddresses=false, ackSndThreshold=32, unackedMsgsBufSize=0, sockWriteTimeout=10000, boundTcpPort=-1, boundTcpShmemPort=-1, selectorsCnt=15, selectorSpins=0, addrRslvr=null, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@59474f18[Count = 1], stopping=false], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@65fb9ffc, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@3590fc5b, addrRslvr=null, encryptionSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.encryption.noop.NoopEncryptionSpi@397fbdb, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=16, txCfg=TransactionConfiguration [txSerEnabled=false, dfltIsolation=REPEATABLE_READ, dfltConcurrency=PESSIMISTIC, dfltTxTimeout=0, txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange=0, pessimisticTxLogSize=0, pessimisticTxLogLinger=10000, tmLookupClsName=null, txManagerFactory=null, useJtaSync=false], cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=80000, sysWorkerBlockedTimeout=30000, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=120000, metricsLogFreq=6000000, hadoopCfg=null, connectorCfg=ConnectorConfiguration [jettyPath=null, host=null, port=11211, noDelay=true, directBuf=false, sndBufSize=32768, rcvBufSize=32768, idleQryCurTimeout=600000, idleQryCurCheckFreq=60000, sndQueueLimit=0, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=7000, sslEnabled=false, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, sslFactory=null, portRange=100, threadPoolSize=30, msgInterceptor=null], odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=1, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=null, memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=DataStorageConfiguration [sysRegionInitSize=41943040, sysRegionMaxSize=104857600, pageSize=4096, concLvl=0, dfltDataRegConf=DataRegionConfiguration [name=Default_Region, maxSize=128849018880, initSize=112742891520, swapPath=null, pageEvictionMode=DISABLED, evictionThreshold=0.9, emptyPagesPoolSize=100, metricsEnabled=false, metricsSubIntervalCount=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, persistenceEnabled=true, checkpointPageBufSize=4294967296], dataRegions=null, storagePath=/ignite/persistence, checkpointFreq=180000, lockWaitTime=10000, checkpointThreads=8, checkpointWriteOrder=SEQUENTIAL, walHistSize=20, maxWalArchiveSize=1073741824, walSegments=10, walSegmentSize=1073741824, walPath=/wal/pincode, walArchivePath=/wal/pincode/archive, metricsEnabled=false, walMode=BACKGROUND, walTlbSize=131072, walBuffSize=0, walFlushFreq=2000, walFsyncDelay=1000,
  walRecordIterBuffSize=67108864, alwaysWriteFullPages=false, fileIOFactory=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIOFactory@2d3379b4, metricsSubIntervalCnt=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, walAutoArchiveAfterInactivity=-1, writeThrottlingEnabled=false, walCompactionEnabled=false, walCompactionLevel=1, checkpointReadLockTimeout=null], activeOnStart=true, autoActivation=true, longQryWarnTimeout=3000, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=30, idleTimeout=0, jdbcEnabled=true, odbcEnabled=true, thinCliEnabled=true, sslEnabled=false, useIgniteSslCtxFactory=true, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null], mvccVacuumThreadCnt=2, mvccVacuumFreq=5000, authEnabled=false, failureHnd=NoOpFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], commFailureRslvr=null]

Edit -2 - GC logs

```
2020-12-01T22:49:31.729+0530: 15.630: [GC pause (Metadata GC Threshold) (young) (initial-mark) 15.630: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 0, predicted base time: 38.43 ms, remaining time: 161.57 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
15.630: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 24 regions, survivors: 2 regions, predicted young region time: 356.58 ms]
15.630: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 24 regions, survivors: 2 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 395.01 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
15.657: [G1Ergonomics (Mixed GCs) do not start mixed GCs, reason: concurrent cycle is about to start], 0.0274990 secs]
[Parallel Time: 15.8 ms, GC Workers: 21]
[GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 15630.2, Avg: 15630.5, Max: 15630.8, Diff: 0.7]
[Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 1.6, Avg: 3.4, Max: 11.4, Diff: 9.8, Sum: 71.8]
[Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
[Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0, Diff: 0, Sum: 0]
[Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
[Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 1.2, Max: 12.6, Diff: 12.6, Sum: 24.2]
[Object Copy (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 9.5, Max: 12.0, Diff: 11.9, Sum: 199.9]
[Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.7, Max: 0.8, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 14.8]
[Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 2.2, Max: 4, Diff: 3, Sum: 47]
[GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 1.0]
[GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 14.5, Avg: 14.8, Max: 15.2, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 311.8]
[GC Worker End (ms): Min: 15645.3, Avg: 15645.3, Max: 15645.4, Diff: 0.1]
[Code Root Fixup: 0.6 ms]
[Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
[Clear CT: 0.5 ms]
[Other: 10.5 ms]
[Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
[Ref Proc: 8.3 ms]
[Ref Enq: 0.5 ms]
[Redirty Cards: 0.5 ms]
[Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
[Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
[Free CSet: 0.2 ms]
[Eden: 192.0M(1008.0M)->0.0B(984.0M) Survivors: 16.0M->40.0M Heap: 198.0M(20.0G)->33.7M(20.0G)]
[Times: user=0.31 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2020-12-01T22:49:31.757+0530: 15.657: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
2020-12-01T22:49:31.764+0530: 15.664: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.0067826 secs]
2020-12-01T22:49:31.764+0530: 15.664: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
2020-12-01T22:49:31.765+0530: 15.666: [GC concurrent-mark-end, 0.0015043 secs]
2020-12-01T22:49:31.766+0530: 15.666: [GC remark 2020-12-01T22:49:31.766+0530: 15.666: [Finalize Marking, 0.0010641 secs] 2020-12-01T22:49:31.767+0530: 15.667: [GC ref-proc, 0.0100232 secs] 2020-12-01T22:49:31.777+0530: 15.677: [Unloading, 0.0072592 secs], 0.0191010 secs]
[Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2020-12-01T22:49:31.785+0530: 15.685: [GC cleanup 37M->37M(20G), 0.0085803 secs]
[Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2020-12-01T22:53:45.090+0530: 268.990: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 268.990: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 0, predicted base time: 30.72 ms, remaining time: 169.28 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
268.990: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 123 regions, survivors: 5 regions, predicted young region time: 1342.47 ms]
268.990: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 123 regions, survivors: 5 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 1373.18 ms, target pause time: 200.00 ms]
269.040: [G1Ergonomics (Mixed GCs) do not start mixed GCs, reason: candidate old regions not available]
, 0.0494933 secs]
[Parallel Time: 31.8 ms, GC Workers: 21]
[GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 268991.8, Avg: 268992.1, Max: 268992.5, Diff: 0.7]
[Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.9, Avg: 1.9, Max: 5.7, Diff: 4.7, Sum: 39.6]
[Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
[Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0, Diff: 0, Sum: 0]
[Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.5]
[Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 1.0, Max: 7.0, Diff: 7.0, Sum: 20.2]
[Object Copy (ms): Min: 21.7, Avg: 28.1, Max: 29.1, Diff: 7.4, Sum: 591.0]
[Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
[Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 21]
[GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 1.8]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 20G heap you may expect to have an eventual full GC taking 4 seconds. I can believe that. Why do you need so much heap with Apache Ignite? How much heap is used during normal course of operations? You may also take a heap dump and search for a memory leak.

Node that Apache Ignite does not store the data on heap by default so it can't be explained by amount of data alone.

I ran your GC log through gceasy.io and it have found several GCs spanning around 2 seconds. I'm not sure it explains your observed 4s pause but you may expect 2s pauses obviously, from GC, which is in the same ballpark.

[image: gceasy.io chart]

So you need to figure out why your JVM becomes slow sometimes. Maybe it's IO, virtualization pauses, etc, etc. Also, if your heap is never larger than 2G, maybe you should run with something like `-Xmx4G`?

Comment: thanks @alamar, there is no memory leak. Max memory usage is 8 GB. I have added ignite configuration in original question. please see above

Comment: Please share GC log of the JVM. I can see that you're collecting it.

Comment: please see the GC logs at the bottom of original post (Edit -2 - GC logs)

Comment: If that's the complete log, maybe you're out of RAM and your system starts swapping. This would explain JVM pauses.

Comment: @alamar: we have set the initial off heap memory to 105 GB and the max off heap memory to 120 GB. Are we running out of this off heap memory? Or are you saying that we might be running out of the 20 G JVM heap ?

Comment: You may be running out of available RAM.

Comment: @alamar: Referred to your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183686/ignite-start-very-slow-when-with-large-xmx-upto-64g-and-could-not-form-cluster
We have 210 GB RAM in each of the nodes. We have set -XmX to 20G and off-heap memory max size to 120 GB. Do you recommend increasing off-heap to ~ 150-160 GB ?

Comment: Please provide full GC log as a file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Q457KxNdPOG0wqiAWCij3hhyMQ3T5js/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see inline